# Efficient way to replace SET/LIST property in Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

In JanusGraph, I want to replace entire value of SET(or LIST) property.
Accoding to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540170/updating-the-entire-value-of-vertex-property-with-list-cardinality-in-titan-grap), both storage backend and index backend (ES, Solr) behavior MUST be taken into account for consistency and efficiency though, the article was written about Titan 1.0.

Currently, I have two option to do it as follows. Which one is better ? Or is there best way to update SET/LIST property in JanusGraph.

- JanusGraph version: github master
- Gremlin version: 3.2.6

### Sample schema

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
person = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('Person').make()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(SET).make()
mgmt.buildIndex('i_person_name', Vertex.class).addKey(name, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex('elastic-search')
mgmt.commit()

person = g.addV('Person').property('name', 'Alexander').property('name', 'Alex').next()
g.tx().commit()
```

### Solution 1

Drop entire property values, and then set new values.

```
new_names = ['Alex', 'Alexander Emmanuel Rodriguez'] as Set

v = g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('name', 'Alexander').next()
g.V(v).properties('name').drop().iterate()
new_names.each{
    v.property('name', it)
}

g.tx().commit()
```

### Solution 2

Drop only old values and set only new values.

```
new_names = ['Alex', 'Alexander Emmanuel Rodriguez'] as Set

v = g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('name', 'Alexander').next()
v.properties('name').each {
    new_names.remove(it.value()) ? null : it.remove()
}
new_names.each {
    v.property('name', it)
}

g.tx().commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop old and add new values in a single traversal. I have to admit it's not the easiest traversal, but it works:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV("person").property(list, "name", "Alexander")
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[Alexander]]

gremlin> new_names = [ "Alex"
                     , "Alexander Emmanuel Rodriguez"] as Set
==>Alex
==>Alexander Emmanuel Rodriguez

gremlin> g.withSideEffect("nn", new_names).
           V().has("person","name","Alexander").as("p").
           sideEffect(
             properties("name").choose(value().where(without("nn")),
                                         drop(), value().store("x"))).barrier().
           select("nn").unfold().where(without("x")).as("n").
           select("p").property(list, "name", select("n")).iterate()

gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[Alex,Alexander Emmanuel Rodriguez]]
```

Comment: It seems elegant, thanks! I did not know withSideEffect which is not written in gremlin reference well. It would be better to read whole gremlin javadoc?

Comment: Not the whole JavaDoc, but it's worth to look at all the available GraphTraversalSource methods: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html